# Call an external function without instantiated its parent class

Tags: c#

I have the following functions in an external class named MyPDF

```
namespace Extensions.PDFs {
    public class MyPDF {
        private IRepository _myRepository {
            get;
        }

        public MyPDF(IRepository myRepository) {
            _myRepository = myRepository;
        }

        public byte[] GetResult1() {
            var data = _myRepository.GetData1();
            return data.ToArray()
        }

        public byte[] GetResult2() {
            var data = _myRepository.GetData2();
            return data.ToArray()
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my controller, I want to get the result of GetResult1().
To do so, for the time being, my only solution is to do:

```
public class MyController
    {
        private IRepository _myRepository { get; }        

        public MyController(           
            IRepository myRepository           
        ) 
        {
            _myRepository = myRepository;            
        }
        
        public FileResult GetPDF()
        {           

            var instance = new MyPDF(_myRepository);           
            var pdfBytes = instance.GetResult1();
            return File(pdfBytes, "application/pdf");
        }    
    }
```

Which means I need to instantiate _myRepository first in my controller in order to then be able to call the external class and its functions. It seems weird to me since _myRepository is not needed at all anywhere else in the controller and is already instantiated in the MyPDF class.

Is there a way to call the functions from the MyPDF class differently?

Hope it is clear enough

Comment: Static methods fits!

Comment: If those are *literally* the methods then obviously it's useless, as you could just call `_myRepository.GetData1().ToArray()` directly. Your code might be oversimplified a bit.

Comment: You said that the repo is "already instantiated in the MyPDF class." Where? Note that `GetResult1` needs the repo.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes it is much more complex than that, I tried to simplify it, perhaps too much.

Comment: @GibbOne I have updated the code to show the controller as well. In my controller, I need to instantiate the MyRepository in order to call MyPDF which sounds wrong. On the other hand MyRepository is also instantiated in the MyPDF class constructor. It doesn't feel right to me to be obliged to instantiate it twice especially in the controller.

Comment: "MyRepository is also instantiated in the MyPDF class constructor" No it's not - a `MyRepository` is _passed into_ the constructor. It sounds like you have some sort of dependency injection framework that does some of that work for you - could you use that to get a configured `MyPDF` instance instead of calling it's constructor directly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get `MyPDF` from dependency injection.

In you controller constructor add `MyPDF` as parameter and it will automatically initialized.

You will be able to use it without initializing manually the repository.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that but got Unable to resolve service for type 'Extensions.PDFs.MyPDF' while attempting to activate Controllers.MyController'.

Comment: Maybe you can add it in the dependency injection initialize step